# Wordpress theme development - widgets have no fields

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom wordpress theme and registered a few different widget areas in functions.php with:

```
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'widget_name',));
```

The widget areas are showing up in dashboard>widgets, however, when I drag a widget in and expand it, the loading wheels appears for a second and then the widget collapses and no longer has any fields or options - just delete, close and the save button.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work for me until I add an 'id' element to that array-- `register_sidebar(array('name'=>'widget_name',id=>'abc'));` Perhaps that is the problem. The [Codex for that function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) is not very clear on what is required. I need to look into that.

Comment: I have put the other elements in including ID, description, before_widget, before_title etc., but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Interesting. That makes me think that something is wrong somewhere else. The code I posted works for me exactly as posted. Try it with all of your plugins disabled and using a default theme.